# What am I missing to pickle and unpickle Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, python-3.x, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm working on a Py3k program that I want to be able to accept Unicode strings and pickle/unpickle them.

However, it is defaulting to an ASCII codec, and complaining about a Unicode error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0161' in position 1442: ordinal not in range(128) 
      args = ('ascii', "Content-Type: text/html\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n...ype='submit'>\n </form>\n </body>\n</html>", 1442, 1443, 'ordinal not in range(128)') 
      encoding = 'ascii' 
      end = 1443 
      object = "Content-Type: text/html\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n...ype='submit'>\n </form>\n </body>\n</html>" 
      reason = 'ordinal not in range(128)' 
      start = 1442 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of UnicodeEncodeError object>
```

How can I change the codec or otherwise change things so that Unicode values taken from a CGI string will be successfully marshalled and unmarshalled as Unicode strings?

Thanks,

--EDIT--

The source code is at http://pastebin.com/nX2w1tqa .

Comment: Please show the code that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and explicitly pass a unicode object to pickle.dump(), something like `pickle.dump(unicode(state), output_file)`

Comment: A shot in the dark... I don't need guessing; I need to know where an ASCII codec is being applied and how to apply a right Unicode codec.